# how to define short key for scroll in form in c#

Tags: c#

how to define short key for scroll in form in c#

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by short key for scroll?

Comment: I bet he means "shortcut key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default keys for scrolling are the arrows.

If you want to redefine them with new keys, you can override your control's `ProcessCmdKey` method and use the arrows when the user clicks on the new keys:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F)
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, Keys.Up);
    else if (keyData == Keys.G)
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, Keys.Down);

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```